# C vs. C++, handling of void** pointers

Tags: c++, c, void-pointers

I found out that using a C compiler the code below works but not with a C++ compiler. I understand that casting to `void**` is the correct usage but I can't understand why it compiles with the C compiler even if I use the `void*` (commented out).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int fn(void **arg)
{
    int *pvalue = *(int**)arg;
    *pvalue = 200;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int value = 99;
    int *pvalue = &value;

    // fn((void *)&pvalue);  // works only in C
    // error C2664: 'int fn(void **)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'void *' to 'void **'

    fn((void **)&pvalue);    // correct, works for both C/C++

    printf("%d", value);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: Because C and C++ are different languages, with different rules?

Comment: @Markus Gilli In C there is allowed to assign a pointer to void to a pointer to any other type without casting.

Comment: Generally speaking, C++ have much stricter type-checking than C. In C++ a pointer to a pointer *must* be a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: You should add the error message to the question! "Not work" is not nice description of an error.

Comment: `(void **)&pvalue` is incorrect and not guaranteed to work in neither C nor C++. "I understand that casting to void** is the correct usage" No it isn't, not in either language.

Comment: The key here is that `void*` is a generic pointer type in C, with special rules asociated with it. But that doesn't mean that `void**` automagically also turns into a generic pointer type. The only difference betwen C and C++ is that C++ doesn't allow implicit conversion between `obj*` to/from `void*` while C allows it. In C++, you would need an explicit cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C there is allowed to assign a pointer of the type `void *` to a pointer of other type. This takes place in this call

```
fn((void *)&pvalue)
```

where the argument has the type `void *` that is assigned to the function parameter that has the type `void **`.

```
int fn(void **arg)
{
    int *pvalue = *(int**)arg;
    *pvalue = 200;
    return 0;
}
```

However such an assignment in general is unsafe. For example the value of a pointer of the type void * can not be properly aligned to be assigned to a pointer of other type.

So it was decided to not allow such an assignment in C++ to make programs more safer.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't understand why it compiles with the C compiler even if I use the void* (commented out).

It compiles because `void*` is implicitly convertible to other pointers in C.

> ```
> fn((void **)&pvalue);    // correct, works for both C/C++
> ```

This may be well-formed because of the cast, the standard doesn't technically give explicit guarantee that conversion to `void**` and back yields the same address.

While this may be likely to work in practice, there is no reason to not use `void*` as the function argument instead, which does have the guarantee. As a bonus, you won't need the cast in the call. Like this:

```
int fn(void *arg);


fn(&pvalue); // correct, works for both C/C++
```

Of course, this is assuming type erasure is needed in the first place. Avoid `void*` when it is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

For avoidance of doubt, there is nothing correct in

```
fn((void **)&pvalue);
```

It is just as incorrect as

```
fn((void *)&pvalue);
```

The correct way to use the API is to do

```
int fn(void **arg)
{
    int *pvalue = (int *)*arg;
    *(int *)pvalue = 200;
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int fn(void **arg)
{
    *(int *)*arg = 200;
    return 0;
}
```

with

```
int main()
{
    int value = 99;
    void *pvalue = (void*)&value;

    fn(&pvalue);

    printf("%d", value);
    return 0;
}
```

You're not allowed to access an object using any other pointer type, other than the declared type, compatible type, or a character type. Furthermore, while `void *` is used as a generic pointer type to all sorts of objects in C, there is no generic pointer to a pointer type in C - other than `void *`!

And this is the reason why the `void **` is almost always a sign of a design error in APIs - most usages are just wrong.